# Copy rows of data from one table to another table in same database using pgadmin

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm quite new to this and I need some help.

I would like to copy rows of data from one table to another table in the same database using pgadmin. However, they have slightly different column id. Is there a way to write a script to match them and do a copy?

Please help. Thank you.

I have tried the following( to copy existing data in STUD table into STUDENT table):

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
Student_id  INT,
Student_name TEXT,
Student_address TEXT
);

INSERT INTO STUDENT
SELECT * FROM STUD AS D
WHERE(
Student_id = D.id,
Student_name = D.name
);
```

I have 2 tables STUDENT and STUD.
Under STUDENT table, I have Student_id, Student_name and Student_address.
Under STUD table, I have name and id.
The rows in the both the tables are not in order.

** ADD ON**
The table in STUD **does not** come with the Student_address column. Only the STUDENT table has. Since STUD does not have Student_address, I would like to put Student_address in STUDENT table as NULL. Is it possible to write a general script where columns in STUDENT table that does not exist in Stud will be NULL?

EDIT**
Instead of NULL, I am required to insert "TBC"

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to use an alias.  Google PostgreSQL Alias.  It takes the form of  < select colid as differentid from table >.  If different data type then use a cast.

Comment: Posting a code sample of what you tried will also help people understand your intent better as well as demonstrate effort on your part.

Comment: Hello. I have included the code.

Comment: What is that `where` statement supposed to do? You can't "join" between the target table and the source table. Are you maybe trying to update _existing_ rows instead?

Comment: I am trying to copy existing data in STUD into STUDENT table.

Comment: @user7609786: then the statement in my answer will do that.

Comment: What if I have multiple extra columns in STUDENT table where STUD does not have(eg. Student_address). Can Student_address become NULL?

Comment: If you don't select it, it will be null for all rows. If include it in the select it will be null for those where it was null and not null for those it wasn't. See my online example: http://rextester.com/ISCL45721 and please stop adding the `pgadmin` tag. This question has nothing to do on how to use pgadmin. It is a pure SQL question, it is totally unrelated to the SQL client you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (:

Comment: The table in Stud not come with the address column. Only the Student table has. As there is no match, I would like to put address as NULL. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an insert based on a select:

```
insert into student (Student_id, Student_name)
select id, name
from stud;
```

The column names don't have to match, only the data types. Any column you do not specify in the insert's target list will be set to `null` (or more specifically to the default value defined for that column)

Online example: http://rextester.com/ISCL45721

**Edit** (after the requirements have changed)

To insert a constant value into one column for all rows, include that constant in the select clause:

```
insert into student (Student_id, Student_name, student_address)
select id, name, 'TBC'
from stud;
```

Comment: The table in Stud does not come with the address column. Only the Student table has. As there is no match, I would like to put address as NULL. Is it possible?

Comment: Then simply don't specify it.

Comment: There are changes. I am required to insert "TBC" instead of NULL for those column that exists in STUDENT but does not exists in STUD. Please help x.x

Comment: See my edit. In general it's not considered polite to change your question after every bit of information you get.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm so sorry I edited it for so many times. No more edit.